# Javascript to load page not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get text from a text input, append it to a URL, and go to that URL, using Javascript. But when I submit, it appears to just reload the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/E3vv6/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadSearchResult(searchToLoad) {
                window.location = "https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=" + searchToLoad;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form onsubmit="loadSearchResult(document.getElementById('googleBox').value)" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Search</legend>
                <input type="text" id="googleBox">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `event.preventDefault()` in the submit function.

**[Live Demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/UTavuSu/1/edit)**

Further, inline js (onsubmit in your html) is bad practice for a lot of reasons. Here are some: https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F

If would be better to get a reference to the form with javascript and attach the event listener.

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  myFunction();
  e.preventDefault();
});

function myFunction() {
  console.log('submitted!'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default behaviour of the `onsubmit`.
You could use `return false`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadSearchResult(searchToLoad) {
                window.location = "https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=" + searchToLoad;
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form onsubmit="return loadSearchResult(document.getElementById('googleBox').value)" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Search</legend>
                <input type="text" id="googleBox">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```